# ASP.NET RDLC report concatenating two fields in one table field

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, report

I return a model from the database containing `userFName` and `userSName` and wish to concatenate them in to a single `name` field in a report table. I've tried the following expressions and each time get `#Error` when the report is rendered.

```
=Fields!UserFName.Value & " " & Fields!UserSName.Value

=Fields!UserFName.Value + " " + Fields!UserSName.Value
```

I stepped through the code and my model is populated properly. I even trimmed the whitespace left over from `char` types thinking that may have something to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my dataset had the field names in lowercase and I'd not refresh and reapplied them to the table.

Lesson learned: case sensitivity is important.